# Google Analytics shows 0 Visits?

Tags: php, javascript, html, security, browsers

I checked Analytics yesterday for pageviews, and had several hundred of them (for yesterday).
Not today when I check "Yesterdays" stats (which yesterday showed several hundreds), it shows 0...?

How come it is 0 all of a sudden?

Anybody been through this?

No messages in GA, WebmasterTools etc. Nothing has been changed on the site...

Just hoping somebody has experience of this before?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't flag your questions with "Urgent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Google had an issue yesterday where their systems went down. It's affected all of the Analytics on our sites.

I don't know why your data would have changed though?
http://www.google.com/analytics/status#rm=1&di=14&ddo=2&hl=en_GB

Comment: Came across this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=696f8756d0b8b064&hl=en